# Program Does Not Run On Win XP But Will Run On Win7

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, windows-xp, stack-trace, invalidoperationexception

So I designed a program using Visual Studio 2010 on a Win7 box. For the sake of this the program is called Test.exe

When another user, using Win XP tries to open this program, it pops up a Just In Time Debugger window and never runs. I can open the program on my Win7 box and additional Win7 boxes and each time the program opens.

I'm not exactly sure where to begin to figure out why Win XP machines fail to run this program.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Here is the exception error we got but running the debugger on the XP machine.

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=WinApp
  StackTrace:
       at WinApp.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create_*Instance*_[T](T Instance)
       at WinApp.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_Form1()
       at WinApp.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at WinApp.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args)
  InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
       Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SignatureStruct& declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
            at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
            at System.Resources.ResourceReader.DeserializeObject(Int32 typeIndex)
            at System.Resources.ResourceReader._LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
            at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
            at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObject(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
            at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean isString)
            at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean ignoreCase)
            at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo culture, Boolean wrapUnmanagedMemStream)
            at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name)
            at WinApp.Form1.InitializeComponent()
            at WinApp.Form1..ctor()
       InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
            Message=The parameter is incorrect
            Source=System.Drawing
            ErrorCode=-2147467259
            NativeErrorCode=87
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Drawing.Icon.Initialize(Int32 width, Int32 height)
                 at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            InnerException:

Comment: Consider debugging the program to see why it's crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make sure that the Windows XP system has the appropriate version of the .NET Framework installed.

Also, there are many types that will not work on XP within .NET framework 4.  For example, if you use the [MD5Cng](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cng.aspx) class, you'll see (in the "Platforms" section of the docs) that it's only supported on Vista+, not on XP.  Using this class in a program will cause an exception if it's run on XP.

---

Edit:

From your stack trace, it looks like your Form (`WinApp.Form1`) is using an Icon (.ico) which is a format that is unsupported by Windows XP.  For example, if you use a full color icon, this can raise an exception on XP.  Make sure it's a 256 color icon file to work properly on XP.

Comment: @Muhnamana Edited my answer - it looks like you're using an icon format that's not supported in XP

Comment: Could this be the icon I'm using on the form? Top left hand corner of the form, by the title?

Comment: @Muhnamana Yes.  Vista+ supports better looking icon formats than XP.  If you're using a "modern" icon, it'll cause an exception on XP.

Comment: Kuddos to @Reed Copsey...you hit the nail on the head with the icon suggestion...I reverted back to the default icon, tested the program on an XP machine, loaded right up.

Comment: I appreciate the help you've given!

Comment: @Muhnamana FYI - including the stack trace in your question is what made that possible - Note the bottom of the stack trace...